# safe args navigation not work in android kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation, arguments

I'am trying to use Safe Args plugin to generate fragment direction that will used to navigate to another fragment with action,i include the dependency but it still not work

gradle project:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
ext {
    version_navigation = "2.3.0"
}

dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
}
}
```

gradle module:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

}
dependencies {
...

// Navigation
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$version_navigation"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$version_navigation"
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: hello, when you say it doesn't works you mean it does not generates the safe args classes, it crashes, or..?

Comment: No it does'nt show -the fragment direction not show to make action ; i try with rebuild app and i close the app and  opened it but both ways didn't work

Comment: Have you set up your directions in the nav_graph.xml, yes? 

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have set all your directions in the navigation graph XML.

If the your directions are set, please clean the project:

- Build -> Clean Project

Invalidate caches and restart:

- File -> Invalidate Caches

If those steps are done and keeps not working, let me know :)

Comment: yes the problem solved thank's  a lot

Comment: please, can you mark the question as valid? 